# Using Rspec on Cloud9 : cannot locate file

Tags: ruby, rspec, cloud9-ide

I am a Ruby newbie, trying to test the following code using the Cloud9 IDE:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative '../calculator'

describe Calculator do
  before { @calculator = Calculator.new('Rspec calculator')}

  it "should add 2 numbers correctly" do
    expect(@calculator.add(2,2)).to eq 4
  end

  it "should subtract 2 numbers correctly" do
    expect(@calculator.subtract(4, 2)).to eq 2
  end
end
```

using: tsa:~/workspace $ rspec spec/calculator_spec.rb

and these are the results:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/calculator_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require_relative '../calculator'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- /home/ubuntu/workspace/calculator
# ./spec/calculator_spec.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./spec/calculator_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00033 seconds (files took 0.14093 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

I would highly appreciate your newbie-friendly advice.
Thanks, Tsa

Comment: it looks like the file `calculator` does not exist, are you sure it is there in the right place?

Comment: please add your project directory structure.

Comment: here it is (in horizontal order):  my-ruby-project -> ... spec -> calculator_spec.rb and spec_helper.rb (inside the spec directory)

Comment: Tamer Shlash: I am sure it's inside the "spec" directory. Should it be somewhere else?